# Way to search and get a panoram image and other info on places

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-search-api, panoramas

I'm building a flutter project.
I want user to input a place(like cafe with green walls, old european street) he wishes to see 3d panorama or image of and than build a grid of recomendations.
I strugle with finding a way to somehow search places and getting pictures and panoramas of them.

Any advice on the APIs that might be useful?

I have tried Google Custom Search API but its json answer rarely has any images and certainly no panoramas and not even coordinates. I'm thinking of finding names of places with Google Custom Search API and then searching for their coordinates witn some other API and then finding a panoram image with some other one...

I'm a beginner so **any advice** on what I'm doing wrong or what I shoud try doing instead would be great.
ty.

tried Google Custom Search API
expicted better way to get info on places such as names, coordinates and images

Comment: Please note that asking for recommendations are not suitable for Stack Overflow. But to help you out, you might want to try out [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service). You can use the library [`googlemaps_flutter_webservices`](https://pub.dev/packages/googlemaps_flutter_webservices) for your flutter app and you can check out this example where it utilizes the Places API autocomplete: https://github.com/Yrll21/googlemaps_flutter_autocomplete_example